# Limit of a function including factorials

Tags: limits, factorial

$$ \lim \frac{(2x)!}{(x! \cdot 2^x)^2} $$

How can I deal with problems including factorials as the same as this problem

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(2x)!}{(x!\,2^x)^2}$? Use `$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(2x)!}{(x!2^x)^2}$`. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ooops, thank you very and very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just play around with the factorials by remembering what they mean

Rewrite as $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2x)!}{(x!*2^x)(x!*2^x)}$$ Now notice that $(2x)!$ is the product of al the integers below $2x$. We could write that as $(2x)_x * x!$ where $(n)_x$ means the [product of all integers below $n$ and above $x$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) Then $x!$ cancels with the denominator and we get
$$\frac{(2x)_x}{2^x(x!*2^x)}$$
Now notice this: $$x!*2^x=(x*(x-1)*\cdots*2*1) * (2*2*\cdots*2*2)$$
Rearrange these factors(put a $2$ next to each factor of $x!$):
$$x!*2^x=(2x)*(2(x-1)*\cdots*(2*2)*(2*1))\leq(2x)_x$$
Which cancels again. We are left with

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2x)!}{(x!*2^x)^2}\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{2^x} = 0$$
So
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2x)!}{(x!*2^x)^2} = 0 $$
(since it can't be negative)

Comment: It's not necessary to invent new symbols. You could use the *[Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)* and write $(2x)!=x!(2x)_x$

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know this symbol. +1!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Note that as x tends to $\infty$, we can use the Stirling Approximation.
That is, for large x, we have 
$$x!\approx\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x$$
We get 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2 \sqrt{\pi x}(\frac{2x}{e})^{2x}}{2\pi x(\frac{x}{e})^{2x}\cdot2^{2x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt {\pi x}}$$
$$=0$$

Comment: knowledge of the nontrivial result of stirling is not necessary in this case, see my elementary answer

Comment: Also, the formula of sterling is not an equality and must always be applied with the knowledge of why it may be applied in that case

Comment: Is this wrong in any way though?

Comment: It was wrong before the edit, now it's right but there is no explaination why you may substitute $x!$ with something it is only approximatly equal to

Comment: These edits are making it a much better answer!

Comment: @JensRenders Thanks to you guys only! (Also I liked your approach as it was more thoughtful +1)